# How to query a particular field of brew cask/ formula info?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, json

Homebrew version on my Mac:

`Homebrew 2.5.0-84-g9e697bd`

Take `github` (Cask for GitHub Desktop) for example, this is the cask file located in `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/github.rb`:

```ruby
cask "github" do
  version "2.5.5-f57dc10d"
  sha256 "fe39c280c746b66d13dbcc5acfeb946f77b680954ecda2bf29a560a98a9d2638"

  # githubusercontent.com/ was verified as official when first introduced to the cask
  url "https://desktop.githubusercontent.com/releases/#{version}/GitHubDesktop.zip"
  appcast "https://github.com/desktop/desktop/releases.atom"
  name "GitHub Desktop"
  desc "Desktop client for GitHub repositories"
  homepage "https://desktop.github.com/"

  auto_updates true

  app "GitHub Desktop.app"
  binary "#{appdir}/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/github.sh", target: "github"

  zap trash: [
    "~/Library/Application Support/GitHub Desktop",
    "~/Library/Application Support/com.github.GitHubClient",
    "~/Library/Application Support/com.github.GitHubClient.ShipIt",
    "~/Library/Application Support/ShipIt_stderr.log",
    "~/Library/Application Support/ShipIt_stdout.log",
    "~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.github.GitHubClient.sfl*",
    "~/Library/Caches/com.github.GitHubClient",
    "~/Library/Caches/com.github.GitHubClient.ShipIt",
    "~/Library/Preferences/com.github.GitHubClient.helper.plist",
    "~/Library/Preferences/com.github.GitHubClient.plist",
    "~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.github.GitHubClient.ShipIt.*.plist",
    "~/Library/Logs/GitHub Desktop",
  ],
      rmdir: "~/.config/git"
end
```

The Cask file has a `desc` field, and it's value is `Desktop client for GitHub repositories`.

However, when I do `brew search --desc github` or `brew search --cask --desc github`, I only get `github: GitHub Desktop`, the `desc` field isn't included.

Sometimes the `desc` field provides valuable information about a cask. So I wonder if there's a way to make `desc` included when doing `brew search --desc` for casks? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#cask-command-options-cask

```
brew cask info github
```

should work.

`--desc` is not listed as a valid option for `cask`.

---

To specifically check a field in the JSON file [`/api/cask/github.json (JSON API)`](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/github#default), use the `info` command with `--json` flag and use `jq` to get the values of a particular field.

While you may find a better way to do it by reading the manual, here's what will work, at least.

```
brew info --json=v1 github | jq "map(.|.desc)"
```

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters
- https://docs.brew.sh/Querying-Brew#brew-info---json

Comment: Yeah that works, but what if I want to view the `desc` of casks when searching for a cask?

Comment: @TeddyC see the updated answer.